# Cmake 3.0.2 Cannot link debug and release libraries from a list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, build-process

We are migrating to Cmake 3.0.2, Visual studio 2013 and building for 64 bits.

What used to work before with Cmake does not work now. I am appending different library names to a list and then want to link all libraries from the list to the project. For example:

```
include_directories("${EMU_EXTERNAL_DIR}/cgal/4.4/include")
link_directories("${EMU_EXTERNAL_DIR}/cgal/4.4/lib/x64")

list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES
debug CGAL_Core-vc120-mt-gd-4.4 
debug CGAL_ImageIO-vc120-mt-gd-4.4 
debug CGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.4
optimized CGAL_Core-vc120-mt-4.4 
optimized CGAL_ImageIO-vc120-mt-4.4 
optimized CGAL-vc120-mt-4.4
)
```

Afterwards I add more libraries the same way. And finally:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES})
```

This leads to VisualStudio searching for the Release libraries while in Debug. If I include explicitely the path to the Release libs as well, then I get a VS error: **"..cannot find lib 'debug.lib'"**. It seems to me that Cmake does not parse the libraries names and the optimized/debug keywords correctly.

Anyone had a similar problem or a clue what is going on? It's pretty confusing since this used to work before.

Thanks!

Comment: They might have enforced how parameters are passed to target_link_libraries: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html you should specify "debug" or "optimized" for each item of the target_link_libraries, not per-element

Comment: can you try specifying the flags directly per each item as the linked documentation says?

Comment: so you mean it should look like target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} debug lib1 lib2 lib3 optimized lib4 lib5), or rather target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} debug lib1 debug lib2 debug lib3 optimized lib4 optimized lib5)(as it is now)?

Comment: the way I understand the documentation of target_link_libraries I can have many items with "optimized" or "debug" keyword in front ... [[debug|optimized|general] <item>].

Comment: I would have thought so either but giving it a try won't hurt

Comment: It is a good suggestion. What I did as a workaround and it works is  that I created two separate lists for debug and release libraries. And it works.  `list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES_DEBUG
 debug CGAL_Core-vc120-mt-gd-4.4 
 debug CGAL_ImageIO-vc120-mt-gd-4.4 
 debug CGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.4
 )
 list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES_RELEASE
 optimized CGAL_Core-vc120-mt-4.4 
 optimized CGAL_ImageIO-vc120-mt-4.4 
 optimized CGAL-vc120-mt-4.4
 )` But this is an ugly work-around.

Comment: what about defining two lists without "debug" and "optimized" inside it and later writing `target_link_libraries(project, debug LIST1, optimized LIST2)` ?

Comment: Thanks @marco-a, your suggestions indeed sounds cleaner. Unfortunately it seems it does not work. Visual studio is then searching for the release library in debug. Totally weird.

Comment: Just to add: it seems it parses the keyword "debug/optimized" only for the first library name immediately after the keyword. So `target_link_libraries(project, debug LIST1, optimized LIST2)` will link the first element of LIST1 in debug and the first element of LIST2 in release. All others are linked to both.

Comment: That's weird, do you still have "debug" and "release" inside LIST1 and LIST2 ?

Comment: Nope. The content of my two lists is the following `LIST_D: qwtd;soqt1d;CGAL_Core-vc120-mt-gd-4.4;CGAL_ImageIO-vc120-mt-gd-4.4;CGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.4
LIST_R: qwt;soqt1;CGAL_Core-vc120-mt-4.4;CGAL_ImageIO-vc120-mt-4.4;CGAL-vc120-mt-4.4`. It links qwtd and qwt correctly and I get an error in VS: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'soqt1.lib'` while building in Debug.